# Multiple IF statements in MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure call which will be updating the client's database. It looks something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_database`()
begin

set @current_version := (select version from testrmaomo.dbase);

-- Only update if v4
if @current_version = '4' then 

    ALTER TABLE `testrmaomo`.`notification` 
    ADD COLUMN `senderID` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `ClientSMS`,
    ADD COLUMN `ClickatellUser` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `senderID`,
    ADD COLUMN `ClickatellPass` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `ClickatellUser`,
    ADD COLUMN `ClickatellApiID` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `ClickatellPass`;

    UPDATE testrmaomo.dbase SET Version = '5';

end if;

-- Only update if v5
if @current_version = '5' then 

    CREATE TABLE `testrmaomo`.`client` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
    `Color` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
    `Client` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '',
    `Address` VARCHAR(400) NULL COMMENT '',
    `Telephone` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
    `Mobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
    `Email` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)  COMMENT '');

    UPDATE testrmaomo.dbase SET Version = '6';

end if;

end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My logic is that if the user's database is v4, it should run both if statements, since the first if statement will update to v5, which should meet the requirements for the second if statement. If the client is already at v5, it will skip the first if statement, and go straight to the second.

For some reason, when I call the procedure, it will only run the first if statement, and only once calling the procedure for a second time will it run the second if.

Is there a way I can get it to run in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @current_version is not updated, of course it is 4.

```
if @current_version = '4' then 
...
    UPDATE testrmaomo.dbase SET Version = '5';

--just update your variable
    set @current_version = 5;
end if;
```

Comment: *facepalm* This is what happens when you've been programming for 8 hours straight. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_database`()
    begin

    set @current_version := (select version from testrmaomo.dbase);

    -- Only update if v4
    if @current_version = '4' then 

        ALTER TABLE `testrmaomo`.`notification` 
        ADD COLUMN `senderID` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `ClientSMS`,
        ADD COLUMN `ClickatellUser` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `senderID`,
        ADD COLUMN `ClickatellPass` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `ClickatellUser`,
        ADD COLUMN `ClickatellApiID` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `ClickatellPass`;

        UPDATE testrmaomo.dbase SET Version = '5';
        set @current_version = 5;

    end if;

    -- Only update if v5
    if @current_version = '5' then 

        CREATE TABLE `testrmaomo`.`client` (
        `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
        `Color` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
        `Client` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT '',
        `Address` VARCHAR(400) NULL COMMENT '',
        `Telephone` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
        `Mobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
        `Email` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)  COMMENT '');

        UPDATE testrmaomo.dbase SET Version = '6';

    end if;

    end$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

you should change current _version variable to 5 in first statement